# Rails 5 ActionCable establish stream from URL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am almost completely new to Rails, or I am sure I would know how to answer this question myself. I am just trying to modify the basic chat app created in the basic ActionCable demo: https://medium.com/@dhh/rails-5-action-cable-demo-8bba4ccfc55e#.6lmd6tfi7

Instead of having just one chat room, I want to have multiple chat rooms, so I modified my `routes.rb` by adding this line:

`get '/rooms/show/:topic', to: 'rooms#show'`

So now I can visit different chat rooms based on different topics. The rooms controller at `/app/controllers/rooms_controller.rb` handles these routes with no problem:

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @topic = params[:topic]
    @messages = Message.all
  end
end
```

But this parameter is not being passed to `app/channels/room_channel.rb`, and I'm just not sure what modifications I need to make. My current attempt:

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "room_channel_#{params[:topic]}"
  end
```

only returns "room_channel_"

Comment: params are available in your views and controllers. if you're hitting a route that exists in a controller you can `p params.inspect` If you aren't in views or controllers you'll need to pass the value in rather than grabbing it from the params hash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here was that I failed to understand from where the subscribed method was being called, and thus did not know how to pass parameters to it.

By reading the actioncable documentation: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable

I found out that the subscribed method is called via *client-side* javascript, not by the rails controller. In the case of the example chat app, this means I had to change the first line of the file `/app/assets/javascripts/channels/room.coffee`

```
App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create "RoomChannel",
```

to

```
App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "RoomChannel", topic: topic},
```

Passing a javascript object to this method allowed me to access those parameters in the `subscribed` method of `rooms_controller.rb`.

Comment: Damn, so close! I just found that snippet on the github branch and I saw you posting the answer. Good research! Just change rooms_controller to rooms_channel

Comment: Doesn't it also need to be changed in the jobs? Like in the chat app example how did you pass the parameter into the perform for "ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel'"?

Comment: @wbruntra, I am facing a very similar problem, and I cannot figure out how you passed a `topic` object to Action Cable. Would you please elaborate how you were to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Set the `topic_id` in a HTML tag, maybe in the `body` tag in your layout file.

```
<body data-topic-id="<%= @topic.id %>">
```

Now read it from JS like this:

```
document.querySelector('body').dataset.topicId
```

Your subscription creation line would look like this:

```
App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create (channel: 'RoomChannel', topic_id: document.querySelector('body').dataset.topicId)
```